# Searching multiple fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing meta data on files and my mappings looks like this:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/myapp/" -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "file": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "path": {
                    "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "user": {
                    "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

There are some other fields too, but they are not relevant to this question. Here 'name' is the name of a file, 'path' is the path to the file and user is the owner of that file. When indexing the data could look something like:

```
{ name: 'foo', path: '/', user: 'dude' }
{ name: 'bar', path: '/subfolder/', user: 'dude' }
{ name: 'baz', path: '/', user: 'someotherdude' }
```

My question is how to build my query so that I can do folder listings given a path and a user. So searching for the user 'dude' and path '/' should result in 'foo'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/) which allows you to specify the queries that must match to constitute a hit. Your query will look something like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [ 
                { "match": { "user" : "dude" } },
                { "match": { "path" : "/" } }
            ]
         }
    },
    "fields": ["name"]
}
```

What this does is checks that there is an exact match for the term "dude" and path "/"

Comment: This works fine if I e.g. curl it on command line. Since I'm in a JavaScript environment and build my query objects directly from JS it becomes problematic due to multiple "must" in the "bool" section. Pondering how to get around that. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Figured it out. Would be nice if you could update your answer to "must" : [ { "match": { "user" : "dude" } }, { "match": { "path" : "/" } } ]

Comment: Nevermind, I edited it myself. This is also a valid js object. Cool with the "fields", didn't know you could limit the search like that.

Comment: @ralphtheninja Thanks for the edit. I did now know that you can wrap multiple items in the must using an array. All this time I have been using the multiple clauses!

Comment: Also fields was suggested by @jackdbernier

Comment: Thanks all to your contributions. It works like a clock here. Very fast and clean! :)

Comment: Glad to help :) elastic search has a really powerful query system. Not much that you can't do with it.

Comment: It's truly amazing and CRAZY fast!

Comment: Thanks ! I was looking for something like this